# How to wrap the first three tags with div?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am getting some dynamic code and I have to wrap the first three element with div. I tried the below code but it's not working.

```
<div class="summary">
    <form class="cart">
        <button></button>
        <div><div></div></div>
        <button></button>
        <button></button>
    </form>
</div>
```

```
$(function(){
    $('.cart').wrap('<div class="product-tab"></div>'); 
});
```

So my expectation output is,

```
<div class="summary">
    <form class="cart">
        <div class="product-tab">
            <button></button>
            <div><div></div></div>
            <button></button>
        </div>
        <button></button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach:

using `.cart>*:lt(3)` as the selector and [`wrapAll()`](https://api.jquery.com/wrapall/)

```js
$(function() {
  $('.cart>*:lt(3)').wrapAll('<div class="product-tab"></div>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="summary">
  <form class="cart">
    <button></button>
    <div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
    <button></button>
    <button></button>
  </form>
</div>
```

**result:**

```
<div class="summary">
  <form class="cart">
    <div class="product-tab">
      <button></button>
      <div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
      <button></button>
    </div>
    <button></button>
  </form>
</div>
```

---

**note:**

According to the [Documentation for `:lt`](https://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/),

> **As of jQuery 3.4,** the :lt pseudo-class is deprecated. Remove it from
> your selectors and filter the results later using .slice(). For
> example, :lt(3) can be replaced with a call to .slice( 0, 3 ).

So you should use: `$('.cart>*').slice(0, 3).wrapAll(...)` for 3.4+ versions.

Answer (score 2):

A note on [Tibebes. M](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65741297/11999748)'s answer: as of jQuery 3.4, the selector `:lt()` is deprecated. You can use `.slice()` as well.
[Source](https://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/)

```js
$(function ()
{
    $('.cart>*').slice(0, 3).wrapAll('<div class="product-tab"></div>'); 
});
```

```css
.summary {
  background-color: red;
}

.product-tab {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="summary">
      <form class="cart">
        <button></button>
        <div><div></div></div>
        <button></button>
        <button></button>
      </form>
</div>
```